# Office Word Add-In clear and turn off tracking changes

Tags: office-addins

Is there a method o property in the Word Add-In API that specifies if the "Track Changes" ribbon button is active?

I am developing a Word Add-In that manages several files. The Add-In loads a file using the insertFileFromBase64 function, before that, the body is cleared using the clear function. Once the document is updated, the Add-In sends the updated data to an API Endpoint and loads another file. The problem is that, if the "Track Changes" ribbon button is active before sends to update the document, when the Add-In loads another file and uses the insertFileFromBase64 function, all content is marked as a change in red color.

In that case is necessary to use the insertFileFromBase64, because if I use the opendocumentFromBase64 function, Word opens a new window but my Add-In needs to be loaded again.